# Turning the contents of a h4 tag another colour, in this case, green

Tags: html, css, colors, formatting

I have the following line of code, and having added the additional bit (font-colour="green") it doesn't in fact turn the h4 title green.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

I also tried added a highlight to the h4 tag, and it removed the left-align feature.

I think the issue may be that I do not understand how it is organised/structured and where I need to make my additions to the code. An explanation of this in any answer would be appreciated.

**Code to turn H4 title green (not working)**

```
<h4 style="text-align:left;width:50%;margin-top:30px;font color="green">Tracking</h4>
```

**code to add highlight to H4 tag**

```
<mark><h4 style="text-align:left;width:50%;margin-top:30px;">Tracking</h4></mark>
```

**with the following in the css**

```
<style>
mark { 
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Along the same lines of formatting for this h4 title text. I tried to add a black line underneath it using

---

and it didn't show up - so whether it was white or transparent I don't know, as it did make a space, but showed no colour.

**I then tried this:**

```
<font color="black"><hr></font>
```

but of course, that didn't work either.

Could the whole problem - with all the examples I've described be something to do with my css? And if so, how do I manually for each individual tag override it to perform the functionality I've described?

Comment: It can't work because of the typo in your `style` attribute; the property is `color` not `font color`; if a CSS rule isn't understood by the user-agent it's discarded; edit the rule to: `color: green`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your style. Instead of `style="text-align:left;width:50%;margin-top:30px;font color="green"` it should be `style="text-align: left; width: 50%; margin-top: 30px; color: green"`

Note the difference between the last parts of both styles.

Comment: Thank you!!! By the same logic, just so I know I understand this, where would I put something in here to make the title 'Tracking' BOLD? or a larger font size? If you could please add that to your answer (both bold and larger font size override) I can accept...thanks again!

Comment: For bold, you could either use the strong-tag or add font-weight: bold to your styles. For font size you could add font-size: 10px for example. In general, I would not recommend you to override the font-size of the heading-tag. Instead, you could use h1-3 or h5-6 depending on your needs.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work: <strong><h4 style="text-align:left;width:50%;margin-top:30px;color:green">Tracking</h4></strong>    should it work?

Comment: The point being, as explained, Im trying to override the styles, as I want this green bold only in a few instances, not across the board

Comment: Could you be more specific? What doesn't work? I just tried it and it's being shown as green and bold

Comment: Well, when I try it, presumably because of my existing styles, it doesn't turn it bold, it simply messes up the alignment and it remains UNBOLD. The issue isn't creating it from scratch, the issue I imagine is how to override styles for an individual h4 .....it isn't working. The green did work though

Comment: I also tried <h4 style="text-align:left;width:50%;margin-top:30px;color:green;strong">Tracking</h4>   which doesn't work

Comment: Put your strong-tag inside of h4 and mark tag. Your hierarchy should be something like <h4><mark><strong> </h4></mark></strong>

Comment: Can you possibly just paste the line of code. What do you mean inside of h4 and mark? Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164891/discussion-between-trojan03-and-misscomputing).